# Value error on CountIf looping through closed workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, function

I want a function that loops through closed workbooks having some parameters given from cells of onother workbook. The aim is to count the number of presence of people in some locations considering a month.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ContMonth(colleague As Range, location As Range, month As Range) As Long

Dim nameMonth As String
Dim nameLocation As String
Dim nameColleague As String
Dim rangeLocation As String
Dim stringMonth As String
Dim file As Variant
Dim count As Integer
        
nameMonth = month
nameLocation = location
nameColleague = colleague

Select Case True
    Case nameLocation = "ponte milvio"
        rangeLocation = "$A$2:$B$2"
    Case Else
        rangeLocation = "null"
End Select
        
Select Case True
    Case nameMonth = "January"
        stringMonth = "-01-2022"
    Case Else
        stringMonth = "null"
End Select
file = Dir("C:\Users\sbalo\Desktop\Test\*.xlsx")

While (file <> "")
    Do While InStr(file, stringMonth) > 0 
        count = count + Application.CountIf("C:\Users\sbalo\Desktop\Test\" & "[" & file & "]" & "Sheet1" & "'" & "!" & rangeLocation, nameColleague)
    file = Dir()
    Loop
Wend
End Function

Sub Test()
Dim counter As Long
Dim name As Range
Dim location As Range
Dim month As Range
Set name = Range("A3")
Set location = Range("B2")
Set month = Range("B1")

    counter = ContMonth(name, location, month)
End Sub
```

this time giving me type mismatching on line:

```
count = count + Application.CountIf("C:\Users\sbalo\Desktop\Test\" & "[" & file & 
"]" & "Sheet1" & "'" & "!" & rangeLocation, nameColleague)
```

Comment: Call your function from a Sub so you can debug

Comment: Can you describe exactly what your function is intended to do?  You mention closed files but there's no `Open` call in your code so what exactly should happen in that `Dir()` loop ?

Comment: Your main problem (even if you fixed your code) is that you are restricted in what you can do from a UDF called from a worksheet cell: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1   Opening other workbooks would be one of those limitations.  Maybe update the code in your post with the code from your deleted answer though, since it seemed like you already made some fixes.