# Function returning #VALUE error in especting integer in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I want a function that loops through closed workbooks having some parameters given from cells of onother workbook. The aim is to count the number of presence of people in some locations considering a month.
I'm getting VALUE error when passing parameters in the sheet.

```
Option Explicit


Public Function count(collega As Range, luogo As Range, mese As Range) As Integer
    
    Dim nomeMese As String
    Dim nomeLuogo As String
    Dim nomeCollega As String
    Dim rangeLuogo As String
    Dim stringaMese As String
    Dim file As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    'Dim count As Integer
    
    count = 0
    nomeMese = mese
    nomeLuogo = luogo
    nomeCollega = collega
    
    Select Case True
        Case nomeLuogo = "ponte milvio"
            rangeLuogo = "$A$2:$B$2"
        Case Else
            rangeLuogo = "null"
    End Select

    Select Case True
        Case nomeMese = "Gennaio"
            stringaMese = "-01-2022"
        Case Else
            stringaMese = "null"
    End Select
    file = Dir("C:\Users\sbalo\Desktop\Test\*.xlsx") 'la funzione Dir permette di looppare senza specificare...

    While (file <> "")
        If InStr(file, stringaMese) > 0 Then 'cerca nella directory il file con il match mese-anno
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\sbalo\Desktop\Test\" & file)
        count = count + Application.CountIf(wb.Sheets("Foglio1").Range(rangeLuogo), nomeCollega)
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        file = Dir
    Wend
End Function
```

Comment: Exactly how are you calling this function - from a cell or from VBA?

Comment: from a cell in the main workbook sheet

Comment: Did you read my comment on your previous post?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/71190085/478884   You cannot do what you want using a UDF called from a cell.

Comment: "Functions can perform a calculation that returns either a value or text to the cell that they are entered in"... that is my purpose...

Comment: I know what functions do, but if you *read the link I posted* you can also see there are things they *cannot do* and this is one of them.